# How do I get the 7 and 10 inch tablet emulators?

Tags: android, android-emulator, tablet

I am using Eclipse. What is the best way for me to get the simulators for the 7 and 10 inch tablets?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You cn download the Galaxy Tab Emulator from the "Android SDK and AVD Manager".Under"Available Packages", "Third party Ad-ons", "Samsung"

Answer (score 11):

create new virtual device on avd manager in eclipse on below screen shot shows 7inch and 10inch screen size choose create and launch them

[image]

Answer (score 2):

The Android emulator images can be installed through the SDK manager.

Beyond that, you can create an emulator for various device configurations by using the Android Virtual Device Manager which comes with the SDK to create them. The prompt will allow you to specify things like RAM, screen size, density and so on.

Documentation on using an AVD can be found [here](http://developer.android.com/tools/devices/managing-avds.html).

Answer (score 2):

If you have an Intel CPU, don't forget to download the Intel x86 Atom System Image and the Emulator Accelerator (HAXM) from SDK Manager. You will also have to change the CPU to Intel in AVDM.

There is also an AMD image, but only for Linux. And it's not in the SDK Manager, you have to set it up manually.

You will be grateful for the great speed.